# Velocity Template for generating custom IntelliJ toString method

Tags: java, intellij-idea, velocity

Given the class

```
public class TestClass
{
    private static List<TestClass> tmp = new ArrayList<>();

    private String test1 = "";
    private String test2 = "";
    private String test3 = "";
}
```

I'm trying to define a custom `IntelliJ` code generation template that will create a `toString()` method in the form

```
public String toString()
{
    final String output = "%s{ test1[%s], test2[%s], test3[%s] }";

    return String.format(output, this.getClass().getSimpleName(), test1, test2, test3);
}
```

I have the following velocity template but the output is not correct.

```
public java.lang.String toString() 
{
#set($i = 0)
final String output = "%s{ #foreach($member in $members)#if($i == 0)$member.accessor [%s]#else,$member.accessor [%s]#end#set($i = $i + 1)#end ";

return String.format(output, this.getClass().getSimpleName() #foreach($member in $members),$member.accessor #end); 
}
```

The output is

```
public String toString()
{
    final String output = "%s{ test1 [%s],test2 [%s],test3 [%s] ";

    return String.format(output, this.getClass().getSimpleName(), test1, test2, test3);
}
```

When I attempt to add a closing brace (}) to the string the template- it fails to render.

I also cannot figure out how to remove the space between each field and its value container (the square brackets), nor can I figure out how to add a space after each comma. I have checked the Apache velocity documentation but  haven't found anything that I can apply.

I know I could use `StringBuilder` and piece the correct elements together to get the same output. However, now getting the Velocity template to work using the above format is a quest :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `${}` instead of `$` for accessing variables, and it will help with the spaces:

```
final String output = "%s{ #foreach($member in $members)#if($i == 0)${member.accessor}[%s]#else, ${member.accessor}[%s]#end#set($i = $i + 1)#end ";
```