# Modify template used in generating `toString` method in Java code editor in IntelliJ

Tags: java, templates, intellij-idea, tostring

I have seen some documentation such as [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generate-tostring-settings-dialog.html) and some Stack Overflow questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52879991/642706) which talk about templates, perhaps Velocity templates, used by IntelliJ when generating a `toString` method in a Java class.

But no where can I find *where* this template lives, or how to access it from within IntelliJ.

➥ Exactly how does one **find and edit the `toString` generation templat**e in IntelliJ 2018?

Comment: It's OK, select `toString()` from the contextual menu. ... now you have one upvote. My only concern: I'm having the Ultimate edition and I'm not sure this feature is available for Community edition.

Comment: @EugenCovaci Well, d'uh! I see now. Thank you.  I did not think about clicking the `Settings` button. I had not realized there was more going on there than a simple pick-list.

Comment: Quite unintuitive that I cannot access the template from the main Settings dialog...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to Code -> Generate and select `toString()` from the contextual menu:

[image]

Next, click the `Settings` button in upper corner.

In the `toString() Generation Settings` window that appears, select `Templates` tab.

[image]

Add template:

[image]

Finally, add the Velocity code then click apply:

[image]

Tip: You can **duplicate an existing template** rather than create an empty one. Click the "double sheets of paper" icon next to the plus and minus icons.

Comment: I do not see any of this when choosing `Code` > `Generate`. See my screenshot added to my Question.

Comment: @user10639668 is there any way that all the current toString methods can be transformed in to a new template that we define using the way you suggested ?

Comment: @vigamage You can duplicate existing templates, but only one at a time, by clicking the sheets-of-paper icon next to the plus and minus icons.